# D3.js: create a fixed number of elements

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to create a fixed number of elements using D3, taking this value from a json file. This means that, if the given json data is **n**, I want to print **n** elements into my svg.

This is my code:

```js
    // Defining the size of the svg element
    var w = 1000;
    var h = 50;

    // Defining the dataset
    d3.json("people.json", function(dataset) {

    // Iterating through the json
    for(var i=0; i<dataset.length; i++) {

                var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                    .attr("width", w)
                    .attr("height", h);

            // Iterating through the value
            for(var j=0; j<dataset[i].age; j++) {

                svg.selectAll("rect")
                        .data(dataset)
                        .enter()
                        .append("rect")
                        .attr("width", 20)
                        .attr("height", 20)
                        .attr("x", function(d, j) { return j * 55 })
            }

        }

    });
```

This is my json example file (totally random values for ages):

```json
  [{
    "name": "Larry",
    "last": "Page",
    "country": "USA",
    "city": "Mountain View",
    "age": 32
  }, {
    "name": "Sergey",
    "last": "Bean",
    "country": "USA",
    "city": "Mountain View",
    "age": 37
  }, {
    "name": "Bill",
    "last": "Gates",
    "country": "USA",
    "city": "Seattle",
    "age": 60
  }, {
    "name": "Mark",
    "last": "Zuckemberg",
    "country": "USA",
    "city": "Palo Alto",
    "age": 35
  }, {
    "name": "Sergio",
    "last": "Marchionne",
    "country": "Italy",
    "city": "Milan",
    "age": 65
  }
]
```

My expected result should be something like that ( [-] --> svg rectangle)

1. Larry Page: 
   [-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-]
2. Sergey Bean:
   [-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-]

and so on...

Can you help me to understand what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Just remove `.data(dataset)` from rects drawing. That's misplaced there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However removing it has as consequence this error: 
get_data_from_json.html?_ijt=4057q09d7k7p7tej2g0mf5objt:56 Uncaught TypeError: svg.selectAll(...).enter is not a function(anonymous function) @ get_data_from_json.html?

Comment: Let me give you an advice, for free: every time you think about using a fior loop in a D3 visualisation, ask yourself: "is this necessary?". In 98.7℅ of the cases it's not necessary (source: FakeData Inc.)

Comment: `selectAll` is misplaced too, like `enter()`. You only need `append("rect")` and set its attributes.

Comment: `data()` and `enter()` are only intended for use with datasets. You have no datasets in your case

Comment: This works, thanks! I'm also interested in the @GerardoFurtado comment... how could I avoid to iterate through my data? I don't get (probably because I'm a newbie) how to avoid the for loop

Comment: First: you have a dataset. Second: removing `data()`, `enter()` etc, makes me ask: why are you using D3? Have a look at the documentation, see some examples, and you'll learn what's the purpose of D3.

Comment: Thanks @GerardoFurtado, I really appreciate your help. I'm using D3 because I think it could serve for my purpose which is, indeed, to visualise data. I want to achieve something different from a bar chart or simple shapes and I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically draw *network devices* based on the number of ports. Am I doing wrong using D3?

Comment: The name of this is "pictogram". It's a very basic task in d3 creating what you want without a single for loop. Right now I'm on my mobile, terrible to write, but I'm sure that someone will soon show you how to do it.

Comment: Thanks again Gerardo, as I told you before I really appreciate your help. But I also said that I'm a newbie and, till now, I never heard about the "pictogram" stuff. Also, I still have no idea on how to achieve that without a single for loop. Since I like your approach and I also think that "free-given" stuff or advices are not the best way to learn stuff, could I ask you for a resource where I could learn to achieve what you said, all by myself?

Comment: When I said pictogram, I was talking about your question, using one rectangle for each year of age, not about this network devices chart. Regarding resources, just leave the question here and wait, someone will soon write a beautiful answer, showing you how to properly create a chart in the "d3 way".

Answer (score 2):

The pure D3 approach would require no for-loops at all (like mentioned by Gerardo Furtado in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39098618/d3-js-create-a-fixed-number-of-elements/39099934#comment65544118_39098618)) and will be something along the following lines:

```
d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
  .data(dataset)              // Bind the entire dataset
  .enter().append("svg")      // Append one svg per object in dataset
  .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) {       // Inherit data from svg by mapping of objects
      // Create an array of number of required rects
      return d3.range(d.age).map(function(d) { return d*15; }); 
    })
    .enter().append("rect")   // Append rects per svg
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return d;             // Position was calculated in above mapping in data()
      });
```

This is all you need to draw the graph you are after (attributes left aside). For a full example setting all values have a look at the following example:

```js
var dataset =   [{
    "name": "Larry",
    "last": "Page",
    "country": "USA",
    "city": "Mountain View",
    "age": 32
  }, {
    "name": "Sergey",
    "last": "Bean",
    "country": "USA",
    "city": "Mountain View",
    "age": 37
  }, {
    "name": "Bill",
    "last": "Gates",
    "country": "USA",
    "city": "Seattle",
    "age": 60
  }, {
    "name": "Mark",
    "last": "Zuckemberg",
    "country": "USA",
    "city": "Palo Alto",
    "age": 35
  }, {
    "name": "Sergio",
    "last": "Marchionne",
    "country": "Italy",
    "city": "Milan",
    "age": 65
  }
];

// Defining the size of the svg element
var w = 1000;
var h = 50;

// Defining the dataset
//d3.json("people.json", function(dataset) {

  d3.select("body")
    .selectAll("svg")
    .data(dataset)              // Bind the entire dataset
    .enter().append("svg")      // Append one svg per object in dataset
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h)
    .selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) {       // Inherit data from svg by mapping of objects
        // Create an array of number of required rects
        return d3.range(d.age).map(function(d) { return d*15; }); 
      })
      .enter().append("rect")   // Append rects per svg
        .attr("width", 10)
        .attr("height",10)
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return d;             // Position was calculated in above mapping in data()
        });


//});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```js
var dataset = [{
  "name": "Larry",
  "last": "Page",
  "country": "USA",
  "city": "Mountain View",
  "age": 32
}, {
  "name": "Sergey",
  "last": "Bean",
  "country": "USA",
  "city": "Mountain View",
  "age": 37
}, {
  "name": "Bill",
  "last": "Gates",
  "country": "USA",
  "city": "Seattle",
  "age": 60
}, {
  "name": "Mark",
  "last": "Zuckemberg",
  "country": "USA",
  "city": "Palo Alto",
  "age": 35
}, {
  "name": "Sergio",
  "last": "Marchionne",
  "country": "Italy",
  "city": "Milan",
  "age": 65
}];

// Defining the size of the svg element
var w = 1000;
var h = 500;
var itemH = 10;
var itemW = 3;
var padding = 2;


// Append svg element
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

// Append groups for each in dataset
var group = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append('g');

// Each group
group.each(function(d, i) {

  //console.log(d);
  var age = d.age;

  var self = d3.select(this);

  // Transform the group in Y
  self.attr('transform', function() {
    return 'translate(0,' + (i * (itemH + padding)) + ')';
  });

  // Append rect forEach from 0 - age
  d3.range(age).forEach(function(i) {
    //console.log(i);

    self.append('rect')
      .attr('width', itemW)
      .attr('height', itemH)
      .attr('x', function() {
        return i * (itemW + padding);
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>


<body></body>
```

Comment: Nitpicking, but the D3 way of doing loops is functional style, ie `d3.range(age).each(function(d, i){  ... })`

Comment: @Duopixel Did you mean forEach? Nice, i've added it to my answer.